# Move Block from Left to Content (Account Nav) Magento (1 Column Layout)

Tags: xml, magento, magento-1.7

I hope this isn't to much of a stupid question, I thought that it would be a basic local.xml update, but cant seem to get it to work.

The issue; I have set  to have a 1 column layout in my Magento site, this then removes the left column (obviously) that holds the 'customer_account_navigation'. I then tried to update my local.xml to move the 'customer_account_navigation' to 'content' but this breaks the site.

Code below, any help with this would be great (excuse any level of stupidity for missing something).

```
<customer_account_index>
<reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
<reference name="left">
    <remove name="customer_account_navigation"/>
</reference>
<reference name="content">
        <block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">
</reference>
</customer_account_index>
```

Many thanks for any help guys.

Comment: It reverts the layout to the base theme.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I finally stopped being an idiot and figured this out. I basically changed the layout of the my account index page in a magento site I am currently developing from a 2 column page to a single column layout. The issue was then adding the account navigation back into the main content of the single column layout... After trying a few things I realised that multiple elements were used to create the account navigation block. I updated my local.xml this morning and finally got it working, code below.

```
<customer_account_index>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-" template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">
             <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account</name><path>customer/account/</path><label>Account Dashboard</label></action>
             <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account_edit</name><path>customer/account/edit/</path><label>Account Information</label></action>
             <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>address_book</name><path>customer/address/</path><label>Address Book</label></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</customer_account_index>
```